# Android non standard navigation design

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation, ui-design

[image]

Hi to all.

I need to implement this kind of navigation in my app. I don't have a clue from where to start. Can somebody point me to right direction?

Comment: You may wish to consider explaining, in detail, what that picture is supposed to represent.

Comment: It supposed to represents some kind of navigation in application (like tab navigation, but tabs must be in this shape and rotated in this angle). Can you understand what i mean?

Comment: You have some type of navigation in all apps (tab navigation, grid navigation, action bar tab or spinner navigation or new navigation drawer). I need it in my app to, but i need it to look like this, and bellow i will have some fragments or something else... Is it clearer now?

Comment: Imagine that in each rectangle is text (HOME, TASK, FRIENDS)...